# Как вытащить определенные символы из строковых данных?

Tags: python, строки

У меня есть путь до файла, в виде `'D:\\Мероприятия\\Майские.png'`, `'С:\\Excel\\Подсчет.xlxs'` и т.д., как можно и строк такого вида вытащить только имена файлов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**вариант 1:**

```
import os
full_name = os.path.basename(path)
only_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
```

самый правильный ибо специализированный именно для этой задачи

**вариант 2:**

```
full_name = text.split('\\')[-1]
only_name = text.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0]
only_name2 = '.'.join(text.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[:-1])
```

недостаток - надо добавить обработку разделителей вида '//'

**вариант 3:**

```
import re
only_name = re.findall(r'[^\\/]+', text)[-1]
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```py
a = 'С:\\Excel\\Подсчет.xlxs'
b = a.split('\\')
c = b[-1]
print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы нашел индекс последнего `\`. Далее после него копировал бы полностью **до точки**.